# Deriving parametric form of Linear Diophantine equation - Circular reasoning

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the derivation of the proof for the parametric form of linear diophantine equation, as in the book by LeVeque, and shown below. [image: desired page]

Here, one thing is certain that the proof relies on the practical knowledge of non-unique (or better, just 'different') values of $x,y$ and $x_0, y_0$, for equal values of $c$ (and of-course for a given $a,b$).  For this scenario, it can occur infinitely many times due to the parametric form of the solution. Hence, sort of circular reasoning is there.

Is there any proof approach, that does not use the equality of $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof cited, for the relatively prime case, first shows that *if* two solutions exist, then they are related as in (7), for some integer $t$. Then it goes on to show that substituting *any* integer $t$ into (7) will produce a valid solution. Putting these two claims together, it arrives at the conclusion that *all* solutions are therefor of the parametric form given by (7). I am not able to find circular reasoning here.

Comment: Thanks, but the way the book derives suddenly in (7) that $t \in \mathbb {Z}$ is unclear to me. Before (7), the fraction $\frac{a}{b} 
= -\frac{y-y_0}{x - x_0}$ does not seem like providing a hint for any integral parameter $t$. Also, the way the (7) is derived is confusing. For me, in (7) : $(y-y_0) = - a.\frac{(x - x_0)}{b} = -at$; and how the negative sign goes away for $(x-x_0)$ derivation is unclear to me. In fact, I feel that $\frac{a}{b}$ is slope in point-slope form, with $c=1$ representing $y$ intercept $1$. So, same value of $c$ means intercept is same, but $x \ne x_0, y \ne y_0$.

Comment: Extending my previous comment, does the same value of $c$ with different values of $x,x_0$ and $y, y_0$ means there are two different lines with same y-intercept?

Comment: Try looking at it from this point of view. Remember that at the point where the book writes $\frac{a}{b}  = -\frac{y-y_0}{x - x_0}$, they are assuming that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, that is, $a/b$ is in lowest terms. So the integer numerator and integer denominator of $-\frac{y-y_0}{x - x_0}$ must be $t$ times  $a$, $b$, respectively, for some integer $t$.

Comment: So, the fraction $-\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} = t. \frac{a}{b}$, I feel that you meant this, rather than "$t$ times $a,b,$ respectively".

Comment: No, I believe that their intention is to have you reason that $-\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} = \frac{ta}{tb}$

Comment: So, this is the crux to parametric form. Drawn equivalent expression for denominator ($x-x_0$) and numerator ($y-y_0$) in terms of any integer $t$. But, this must be having base in point-slope form (assuming no circular reasoning!), as any lattice (integer pair of ($x,y$)) point lying on the line $ax+by =c$, with next point to have suitable increment of $x,y$ values. These 'suitable' increments define the parametric form of the solution, in terms of deriving any general solution ($x_0, y_0$) in terms of P.S. ($x,y$).

Comment: Anyway, if there are different lattice points on a line (defined by the parametric form for 'suitable' increments of $x,y$) with same slope ($\frac{a}{b}$) and same $y$-intercept ($c$), then there can be infinitely many points. Issue is finding such points with the parametric form. This parametric form is just an equivalent form derived (in proof) from the same slope and same $y$ - intercept line's two different points.

Comment: If it is all not circular reasoning, then it is using two equivalent axioms, to derive the parametric form.